# SAS Macro in order to create a table according to an indexed array?

Tags: arrays, list, macros, sas

I have a table with 5 variables :

id year_beg year_end month_beg month_end

I would to create a table which has year in column, month for each obno when the year/month match with the duration of the object according to previous table.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your dataset?

Comment: Seems like proc transpose can do the trick but I need to have a look into the dataset

Comment: Yes of course, thanks.

Comment: Object_id Yr_beg Month_beg Yr_end Month_end (169330, 1998, 12, 2008, 11) (169331, 1999, 5, 2005, 6)

Comment: I'd like to get : 1998 12 169330 ... 1999 5 169331 ... 2005 6 169331 ... 2008 11 169330 so on so fourth so that I get for each year each month for each object a line. I hope that it's clear.

Comment: I don't see any difference in the data you posted in the comments. Can you edit the question to put in the data?  Is the objective to expand the time period your original variables imply into multiple records?

Comment: Yes that's the objective Tom. Here I think I might have come up with a solution, but not sure it's the easiest one ;

Comment: %macro corps;
%do annee = 1999 %to 2016;
 %do mois = 1 %to 12;
  proc sql;
  create table out_&mois&annee as
  select &annee as year, &mois as month, obno
  from test3
  having mdy(&mois,1,&annee) between beg and end or 
  (-1 + intnx("month",mdy(&mois,1,&annee),1)) between beg and end
  ;
  quit;

  
 %if &mois = 1 %then 
 %do;
  data out_&annee;
   set out_&mois&annee;
  run;
 %end;
 %else
 %do;
  data out_&annee;
   set out_&annee out_&mois&annee;
  run;
 %end;

 proc sql;
 drop table out_&mois&annee;
 quit;

 %end;

Comment: %if &annee = 1999 %then 
 %do;
  data out;
   set out_&annee;
  run;
%end;
%else
%do;
 data out;
  set out out_&annee;
 run;
%end;

proc sql;
drop table out_&annee;
quit;


%end;
%mend;

Comment: Post both your data and code by EDITING your question. It's almost impossible to read code in the comments due to no line breaks.

Comment: Ok Reeza, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

`Obs OBNO beg end` 
 `1 169330 36503 39778` 
 `2 169331 36501 39274` 
 `3 173535 36369 39511` 
 `4 173704 36424 39468` 
 `5 185348 36517 39630` 
 `6 186455 36658 39476` 
 `7 188162 36690 39344` 
 `8 190160 36767 39433` 
 `9 190164 36803 39469` 
 `10 192073 36803 39526`

`%macro corps;`    
 `%do annee = 1999 %to 2016;`    
  `%do mois = 1 %to 12;`   
   `proc sql;`  
   `create table out_&mois&annee as`  
   `select &annee as year, &mois as month, obno`  
   `from ent.Bornescontrat`  
   `having mdy(&mois,1,&annee) between beg and end or`   
   `(-1 + intnx("month",mdy(&mois,1,&annee),1)) between beg and end`  
   `;`  
   `quit;`  
     
     
  `%if &mois = 1 %then`    
  `%do;`   
   `data out_&annee;`  
    `set out_&mois&annee;` 
   `run;`  
  `%end;`   
  `%else`   
  `%do;`   
   `data out_&annee;`  
    `set out_&annee out_&mois&annee;` 
   `run;`  
  `%end;`   
     
  `proc sql;`   
  `drop table out_&mois&annee;`   
  `quit;`   
     
  `%end;`   
     
     
 `%if &annee = 1999 %then`     
  `%do;`   
   `data ent.out;`  
    `set out_&annee;` 
   `run;`  
 `%end;`    
 `%else`    
 `%do;`    
  `data ent.out;`   
   `set ent.out out_&annee;`  
  `run;`   
 `%end;`    
     
 `proc sql;`    
 `drop table out_&annee;`    
 `quit;`    
     
     
 `%end;`    
 `%mend;`

Comment: beg and end are dates.